# Is there a way to delete the Account folder from a Razor VS project?

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-code

I have loaded Visual Studio 2017 in the last year, and when going to create a Razor project now, this creates an Account folder containing several files for user authentication.  I do my own authentication in a database and don't need these files.
Now using the .NET Framework 4.5 these appear to be required, even though I don't use them. 
Is there any way to remove this Account folder and OAuthWebSecurity files?

Comment: The related question is can I disable this authentication?  I have looked for 2 days and don't see a way.

Answer (score 0):

The `Account` folder is create only when you use the default authentication type `ASP.NET` has, one thing to do if you don't need it is not to create it in the first place.

**If you don't want to create it**

- When creating a project in Visual studio make sure No Authentication is selected by clicking on the `Change Authentication` button
- Select `No Authentication` option and click `OK`
- Click `OK` again to create the project.

**If you inherited a project that already has the Folder and you don't want to use them**

- You can delete the Account Controller and also remove anywhere it was invoked eg. in the `Manage Controller`
- Remove `IdentityConfig.cs` file from `~/App_Start` directory
- Remove all the Views in the `~/Views/Account` directory
- Remove `Account`, `Idnetity` and `Manage` View Model files in `~/Models` directory
- Since you are implemeting your own authentication, you know what to do in the `Startup_Auth.cs` file
- Build and ensure no errors
- there might be other file you need to remove.